# how to open aspx page inside of a table cell using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my Project I have a table on which I use a cell in order to open various pages with different works.
I use that script:

```
Dim url As String = "../../Pages/Support/Asp/Help01.aspx"

Dim msg As String = "<script type='text/javascript'> 
document.getElementById('iFrame').innerHTML = " +
"$(document).ready(function(){  window.location.href='" + url + "';  }); 
</script>"

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myURL", msg)
```

For this purpose. But what I get is to close the current page and open (in full screen) the new page.
How can I make the new page to open inside of the table cell which I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `<iframe>` and change its **src** attribute with JavaScript not innerHTML.

Check these links:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp